# Podspec Lint and Trunk Push Error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I am running the following command:

```
pod spec lint --verbose
```

I am getting the output

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
-> MyFramework (0.1.0)
-> MyFramework
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
```

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod spec lint --verbose
```

#### Report

```
* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?
```

#### Stack

```
CocoaPods : 0.39.0
    Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
RubyGems : 2.0.14
    Host : Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
   Xcode : 7.2 (7C68)
     Git : git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ cee10ce570256b26ee525b1d6868e2f486b3df92
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-plugins : 0.4.2
cocoapods-search  : 0.1.0
cocoapods-stats   : 0.6.2
cocoapods-trunk   : 0.6.4
cocoapods-try     : 0.5.1
```

#### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `to_sym' for #<Hash:0x007ff9ab949088>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/root_attribute_accessors.rb:198:in `block in convert_keys_to_symbol'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/root_attribute_accessors.rb:196:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/root_attribute_accessors.rb:196:in `convert_keys_to_symbol'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/root_attribute_accessors.rb:113:in `source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:109:in `block in check_required_attributes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:108:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:108:in `check_required_attributes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:50:in `lint'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:243:in `perform_linting'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:77:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:60:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:50:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
```

I don't know why this error is occurring. I can't find any method called to_sym. I have updated my podspecs, and gotten rid of all errors. I have registered with pod trunk. Now all I am trying to do is get a valid lint and push to the trunk. I am attempting to do this via http. Not sure if that affects anything, but I know most people do this via a git source. I created the library and even have an example project in here.

Comment: Please post the podspec that is failing

Comment: SOLUTION: I was pushing up the .podspec file and not the podspec.json file

Comment: Pushing the podspec file should convert it to JSON. Based on the stack trace the conversion failed because of invalid syntax in the ruby version.